# p:dialog doesn't work in explorer and chrome, but works in eclipse internal web browser

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have the following XHTML code

```
<ui:define name="content">
<center>
  <h:form id="form">
     <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" /> 
     <p:panel header="Selectionner un fournisseur" style="width : 664px; " >  
        <br />
        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{fournisseurbean.LF}" rowKey="#{car.idfournisseur}"  
                 selection="#{fournisseurbean.selectedfour}" selectionMode="single">  
           <f:facet name="header">  
           Liste de fournisseurs  
           </f:facet>  

           <p:column headerText="Nom de fournisseur">  
            #{car.nomfour}  
           </p:column>  

           <p:column headerText="Personne à contacter">  
            #{car.persocontact}  
           </p:column>  

           <p:column headerText="Téléphone" >  
            #{car.telephone}  
           </p:column>  

           <p:column headerText="Fax">  
            #{car.fax}  
           </p:column>  

           <f:facet name="footer">  
              <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="Select " icon="ui-icon-search"  
                    update=":form:display" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()"/>  
           </f:facet>  
        </p:dataTable>  

        <p:dialog id="display" header="Fournisseur selectionné" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="true"  
              width="300" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">  
            <p:commandButton    value="Next"  oncomplete="document.location.href='#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/faces/Gestionstock/Bondecommande/Selectmateriaux.xhtml'"   action="#{fournisseurbean.SetfourenBC()}"/>
         </p:dialog> 
    </p:panel>  
  </h:form>
</center>
</ui:define>
```

which is a primefaces 4.0 datatable single selection shown in this [Link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf)
The Buttom which show the dialog (id="viewButton") use to work fine  in all web brosers , but it suddenly stopped working , althought i didn't change anything in this part , when i tried this code on eclipse internal web browser it works , but in other browsers it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebug or Webdeveloper tools from a browser to test these things:

1. JavaScript errors
2. Is the right CSS style applied?
3. Are you using jquery and is there a conclict between your version and Primefaces' one ?

Comment: That magically worked just by installing firebug on my browser !! listen i don't really get what's happened!!! now my application is working even Firebug is off althought i didn't modify anything !!!